# Broken package, but cannot purge or reinstall it!

Tags: package-management, 16.04, dpkg, mdadm

My mdadm package is not fully installed, when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I see the following error message:

```
Setting up mdadm (3.3-2ubuntu7.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 20
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mdadm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to purge mdadm with `dpkg --purge mdadm` to reinstall it later, but the system tells me: `ubuntu-server is dependent on mdadm`.

I already tried the solutions suggested by http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
sudo dpkg –configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I also tried to edit the dpkg-status-file manually and removed the block of information about mdadm, the error still remains.

Any help is very appreciated...

---

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Linux 4.4.0-24-generic on x86_64.

Comment: Short question: Is your problem still existing? I have a possible solution that could work for you.

Comment: Yes. this problem still exists.

Comment: I added some alternatives in the answer, give it another try...

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1**: Try to reinstall mdadm with *apt-get*:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install mdadm
```

---

**Alternative 2**: If *apt-get* doesn't work, install *Synaptic* with the Software Center.

Go to the search section and type mdadm, right-click and mark it for reinstallation (or try all the other options) and apply the execution.

---

**Alternative 3**: If no luck so far, try to reinstall mdadm from the .deb-file directly:

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/mdadm_version.deb
```

Use tab-completion, because the .deb-file is additionally named with a version number!

Is there no such package in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, you may need to [download](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mdadm) it manually. Take care that you choose the correct Ubuntu Release and the correct Package Version!

```
sudo dpkg -i path-to-downloaded-package/package-name-version.deb
```

In case that dpkg doesn't work either, install *GDebiPackageInstaller* with the Software Center and reinstall the downloaded .deb-file with this program.

---

**In the end, clean-up and update your system**:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge
dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` cannot proceed because of the same error as listed above. I did not have deborphan installed so I tried `sudo apt-get install deborphan` but it couldn't complete because dpkg errored out trying to process mdadm

Comment: what happens when you run: sudo apt-get --reinstall install mdadm

Comment: `E: Internal Error, No file name for mdadm:amd64` is the error message

Comment: and 'sudo apt-get -f install mdadm'?

Comment: the original error message
    `dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):`
     `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 20`
    `Errors were encountered while processing:`
     `mdadm`
    `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: try the alternative as added in the answer and give me feedback...

Comment: I already did that before posting here and I still get the original error message.

Comment: Try this: 'dpkg --purge mdadm', if it works, reinstall mdadm

Comment: I did try that (mentioned in the original post) but it didn't let me purge because ubuntu-server is dependent on mdadm

Comment: alt 1 and alt 3 both give me the same error message. i can't do alt 2 because it's a remote ubuntu server without a desktop environment. I also ran `sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 mdadm` and it gave the following error: `dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 20
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mdadm`

Answer (score 0):

The 'clean-up' commands in previous answer include some things which are potentially dangerous, especially piping to `xargs dpkg --purge` without inspecting the packages to be removed.

In any case, this whole 'clean-up' is not going to help. Look in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mdadm.postinst`. I'm afraid you'll have to examine the script, potentially running segments of it manually, to see how it is failing. Often, these scripts just stop a service or remove a few files, which you can do manually. If you think all the scripts actions are avoidable, you can remove the script and try to reinstall the package again.