# Mdadm blocks apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, mdadm

So

Mdadm seems to cause an error when trying to upgrade packages.
`apt-get upgrade` results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mdadm (3.3-2ubuntu7.2) ...
dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 128
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mdadm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The same error is limiting me to install e.g. meld `sudo apt-get install meld`

also results in

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mdadm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried [Broken package, but cannot purge or reinstall it!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786356/broken-package-but-cannot-purge-or-reinstall-it) without any success.

`apt-get -f install` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mdadm (3.3-2ubuntu7.2) ...
dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 128
Errors were encountered while processing:
  mdadm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas on what to do? I'm on Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: can you paste the output of: `apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved by the removal of the `mdadm` package:

```
sudo apt-get install -f mdadm-
```

For good measure I ran a package upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have software RAID, then mdadm is needed.

```
dpkg --unpack /var/cache/apt/archives/mdadm_3.3.2-5+deb8u2_amd64.deb
dpkg --configure mdadm
```

This workaround worked for me. (example for debian)

Answer (score 0):

The above methods didnt really work for me ... .. the   apt-ge tinstall -f mdadm-   would have removed things that i needed

I solved it like this:

```
dpkg --force-all --remove mdadm
dpkg --force-all --purge mdadm
apt-get install -y mdadm
```

this avoided removing dependancies that depended on mdadm